# Running .exe file using QProcess creates hundreds of the same processes

Tags: qt, phantomjs, qprocess

I have a problem running phantomjs.exe binary in my QProcess class. Consider this code:

```
QString program = "phantomjs.exe";
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
process->start(program, QStringList() << "test.js");
```

When I start the app main process loads up and nothing happens after that, just hundreds of other phantomjs.exe are created (checking it in TaskManager) as well as conhost.exe processes.

I tried other exe files, like notepad.exe, and it works just fine. Notepad window appears.

Did you encounter this problem?

Comment: I have not seen this and I use QProcess for several of my applications on windows. Although I am limited to Qt-4.8.5 because of library dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking I found that there is a problem with QProcess. I used SHELLEXECUTEINFO instead. This code works for me well. No recursive calls of phantomjs.exe here:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo;
shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);

shExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
shExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
shExecInfo.lpVerb = L"runas";
shExecInfo.lpFile = L"phantomjs.exe";
shExecInfo.lpParameters = L"test.js";
shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
shExecInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
shExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you call `phantom.exit()` in your test script?

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start

```
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello phyatt. Thanks for your answer. Yes, I call `phantom.exit();` at the end of the script.